# Python encoding error when trying to print a QString

Tags: python, qstring, python-unicode

I try to print a PyQt4.QtCore.QString object:

```
print str(type(html))
print str(html)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
<class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 23, in <module>
    print str(html)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2039' in position 4165: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with

```
print unicode(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.x `str` returns an `ascii` string. So if there is a unicode character in your input, it can not be converted. The `unicode` function serves you instead then.

If you use for example python 3.3, `str` function would have an `encoding` parameter which is `utf8` by default. Therefore you won't see the error.

Look [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-str) for more fetails.